# Cannot use variable in button submit handler

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to create a button that, when clicked, not only submits information but changes the button's display text. I've got the submitting part done (thanks to a tutorial from Google), but I'm stuck on the display text. This is what I have:

```
// submit form
var submitButton = container.createButton();
submitButton.setText("Submit");
decorateLabel_(submitButton);

// submit handlers
var submitServerHandler = container.createServerClickHandler('submitHandler_');
submitServerHandler.addCallbackElement(vPanel);
submitButton.addClickHandler(submitServerHandler);

function submitHandler_(e) {
  submitButton.setText("Submitted"); // <-----------------------------
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var timeSheet = getFormData_(e);
  submitPage_(app,e, timeSheet);
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

I've placed an arrow indicating the line that is giving me trouble. When I run the script, I get the following error: "Error Encountered: submitButton is not defined"

I am sure this is a very simple thing, but I'm very new to scripting. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The handler is called from a different scope when the submit happens, where the button isn't defined.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to define the button in that scope?

Comment: Don't really know, GAS is different when it comes to scopes, globals and a lot of other things.

Comment: You might be better off in the long run using HTML Service.  The UI service was deprecated on December 11, 2014.  [Google Documentation - UI-App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/ui-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function submitHandler_(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var submitButton = app.getElementById("YOUR_SUBMIT_BUTTON_ID");
  submitButton.setText("Submitted"); 
  ...`

Comment: inserting the `var SubmitButton` line gets OP past the error